# What Am I Doing Wrong with this API Function to Get Data with Form Input?

Tags: javascript, html, api, post, get

I have tried everything. I am trying to take the form data from user input and store it in a variable, then get data back from my API and display to the same screen.

Here is what I've been working for over 4 days on:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      var $keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
      const data = null;
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
        }
      });

      xhr.open("GET", "https://google-search3.p.rapidapi.com/api/v1/search/q=iphone&num=100");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-User-Agent", "desktop");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Proxy-Location", "US");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "d227f69184mshb8f34a71194a017p1c3f21jsncff472656cdc");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "google-search3.p.rapidapi.com");

      xhr.send(data);
```

```html
<p class="w3-xlarge">Enter a Keyword Below:</p>
<FORM id="form" NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
  Enter something in the box:
  <BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="text" id="keyword" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="">
  <P>
    <button type="submit">Get Links</button>
</FORM>
```

Comment: You're missing `})` at the end of the call to `addEventListener`

Comment: You're not adding `$keyword` to the URL.

Comment: It's the 2020's, you should be using `fetch()` rather than XMLHttpRequest.